# Set variable value in C# async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await

I've got model where I set receiver in `async` method, and then if email is of type X I need to generate URL from other two objects. However `model.Url` doesn't get assigned while reciever gets assigned.  How should I fix it to work for both?

```
private async Task GenerateUrl(Model model)
{
    var urlModel = GetUrlByOrganizationId(model.OrgId);
    var org = GetOrg(model.Id);
    model.Url = brand.Domain + org.Name;
    await Task.FromResult(model.Url);
}

private async Task<Email> GenerateEmail(User receiver, Guid brandId)
{
    var model = new Model()
    {
        title = "",
        Organization = organization,
        Url = string.Empty
    };

    try
    {
        await model.SetReceiverAsync(receiver, 0, model.Locale, model.Dialect);
        await this.GenerateUrl(model);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        this.Log(LogLevels.Warning, exc.Message);
        return null;
    }


    // Send email
    var email = Sender.RenderModel(template, model);
    return email;
}
```

I want to use `model.Url` in `var email = Sender.RenderModel(template, model);` line

Comment: Is it throwing an exception? Could be that GetUrlByOrganizationId or GetOrg is failing. Open the Exception Settings window in VS and turn on "Break When Thrown" for all "CLR Exceptions" for an easy way to have your code stop in the debugger as soon as any managed exception is thrown (caught or not)

Comment: Note; what do you use `var urlModel` for? Assigned a value but never used? Did you intend to use it but used model instead causing a null ref etc?

Comment: I see that you missed generic type here 
`Task GenerateUrl(Model model)` 
`Task<String> GenerateUrl(Model model)`
That makes more sense as you return the string via Task.FromResult(mode.Url).

Comment: so it appears that in `GenerateUrl(Model model)` my model comes as `null` even though I set value to it before calling method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear why `GenerateUrl` is defined as an `async` method and return a `Task`. If it simply sets the `Url` property of the model, it should be define like this:

```
private void GenerateUrl(Model model)
{
    var urlModel = GetUrlByOrganizationId(model.OrgId);
    var org = GetOrg(model.Id);
    model.Url = brand.Domain + org.Name;
}
```

And called without `await`:

```
this.GenerateUrl(model);
```

If you intend to return the URL from the method, the return type should be either `string` or `Task<string>` (the latter doesn't make much sense given the current implementation though):

```
private async Task<string> GenerateUrl(Model model)
{
    var urlModel = GetUrlByOrganizationId(model.OrgId);
    var org = GetOrg(model.Id);
    model.Url = brand.Domain + org.Name;
    return Task.FromResult(model.Url);
}

private async string GenerateUrl(Model model)
{
    var urlModel = GetUrlByOrganizationId(model.OrgId);
    var org = GetOrg(model.Id);
    model.Url = brand.Domain + org.Name;
    return model.Url;
}
```

Comment: thank you! I used the first part, I rebuilded my backend and everything started to work